# how to get and use external html safely with python

Tags: html, python-3.6

I fetch external untrusted html (export from etherpad) via python. How can I be sure, that there is no "bad code" included? I could of course just strip all  for example, but is that already all of it? Is there a library that does the work reliable?

Comment: Well, what is save? You could strip all tags; you could strip all scripts and styles; you could parse the incoming html and use only a white list of allowed tags and attributes; you could parse the html and show like before, with 'componentized' ids, classes and style rules (like Angular does for Components or Gmail does for styles). You can go arbitrary complex

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it by using python module `bleach`